# Resetting Redis sorted set

Tags: sorting, redis, phpredis

I m using redis server to sort scores in an online game.

The gameplay is divided into play sequence of 2-3 minutes and after each sequences scores are displayed and user get his rank (zadd, zrevrank)

All is ok with this, but how do I can reset my sorted set after my play sequence ? I found ZREM but looks like I have to specify keys. is there a quick way to remove all values from the sorted set ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you simply use

```
del setname
```

To delete the set?

Comment: yes , I found del to be the solution, I was looking for something specific to ordered set, but del works for all kinds of keys. thanks :)